# Colours look duller on Matte or glossy finish?

Tags: color, print-design

It is my first time printing and I'm saddened by the fact that the colours have come out to too dull (the print review was given on a matte finish). Although there are other factors that contribute to colours falling flat, I would like to know would colours look brighter on a glossy paper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit pictures that have turned out to be too dark on print?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93140/how-to-edit-pictures-that-have-turned-out-to-be-too-dark-on-print)

Comment: Ask your printer for samples of their finish options.

Answer (score 1):

In the broad, general, scheme of things, colors will be *percieved* as slightly more vibrant on gloss stock because ink isn't absorbed as much into the substrate. But the difference is really minute in most instances. So minute, that one should *never* try and rely on stock choice to dictate the vibrance of any color.

And this assumes the stock *is* a gloss stock. It is entirely possibly to print on a matte or dull coat stock, then add an aqueous coating or varnish on top of the ink. This makes the piece appear glossy without actually being printed on a gloss stock.